# UE4 How to get components of blueprint class in c++?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

[image]

I have blueprint class that created inside of unreal engine editor, (Not Deriven by c++) and there's bunch of staticmeshcomponent is added.

How to get all those component from c++ class?

What i tried :

TileGenerater.h

```
TSubclassOf<TileActor> TileType;
```

TileGenerater.cpp

```
AActor* TileActor = TileType.GetDefaultObject();
auto TileComponents = TileActor->GetComponents();
```

and TileComponents has no elements.

I think GetComponents is working only for actor which spawned into world.

Help me!

Comment: What is being assigned to TileType? Is that your BP class?

Also I don't think getting the default object is what you want to do here, but I'd need to know more about why you're trying to get all the components.

Answer (score 0):

Try using FindComponentByClass and specify UStaticMeshComponent.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You should use **GetComponents**() function on the actor, and pass a class name as a template argument, like so:

```cpp
if (ActorRef) {
    TArray<UStaticMeshComponent*> staticMeshes;
    ActorRef->GetComponents<UStaticMeshComponent>(staticMeshes);
    for (UStaticMeshComponent* mesh: staticMeshes)
    {
        // do whatev
    }
}
```